# How can I access and edit one object deeply inside another object (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nested-loops

How can I avoid nested loops, in order to access the deeply nested object like the below example?

**Sources -> [categories] -> [SubCategoryies] -> [Source]**

I need to access one ***Source*** by ID and change its values

code sample with nested loops

```
        self.sources?.categories.forEach({ (c) in
            c.subCategories.forEach({ (sc) in
                sc.sources.forEach({ (s) in
                    if s.sourceId == String(AddedSource)
                    {
                        s.selected = "1"
                    }
                })
            })
        })
```

Please advice.

Comment: is it a one-time loop, or do you have to run this loop often? If one time, it might be ok as is. If often, you can expose all inner objects in 1 loop, and access them directly afterwards. If `sourceId` is unique across all categories, it can be something like [String:Source] dictionary; if `sourceId` is not unique, you may need [String:[Source]] - array of Source objects by their `sourceId`

Comment: do you know the category and subcategory of the source or you only know the source id when you start the search?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't any more efficient but it gets the job done without having to code ForEach loops. Here is the setup:

```
import Foundation

struct MainSource {
    var categories = [ Category ]()
}

struct Category {
    var subcategories = [ Subcategory ]()
}

struct Subcategory {
    var sources = [ Source ]()
}

struct Source {
    var sourceID: String
}

let sA = Source( sourceID: "A" )
let sB = Source( sourceID: "B" )
let sC = Source( sourceID: "C" )
let sD = Source( sourceID: "D" )
let sE = Source( sourceID: "E" )        // this is the one to find
let sF = Source( sourceID: "F" )
let sG = Source( sourceID: "G" )
let sH = Source( sourceID: "H" )
let sc1 = Subcategory( sources: [ sA, sB ])
let sc2 = Subcategory( sources: [ sC, sD ])
let sc3 = Subcategory( sources: [ sE, sF ])
let sc4 = Subcategory( sources: [ sG, sH ])
let cA = Category( subcategories: [ sc1, sc2 ])
let cB = Category( subcategories: [ sc3, sc4 ])
let mainSource = MainSource(categories: [ cA, cB ])
```

And here is an "answer":

```
let foundSource =
    mainSource.categories
        .flatMap{ $0.subcategories }
            .flatMap{ $0.sources }
                .filter{ $0.sourceID == "E" }
                    .first
print("The found source has a sourceID of: '\( foundSource?.sourceID ?? "not found" )'.")
```

In Playground this will do the job. At the end it prints:

```
The found source has a sourceID of: 'E'.
```

**EDIT:** I set this up with value types, so in this case you wouldn't be able to change the value of the 'source' instance recovered from within the nested arrays. It should work if you're using classes, however.